# WPF change Password property of PasswordBox in PasswordChange event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to do the following:

```
private void PasswordBox_A_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
PasswordBox_A.Password = PasswordBox_A.Password.Replace("\n", "");
}
```

but the thing is This code is executed infinitely. I just want to make sure that the user doesn't write the string "\n", do yow know other method or maybe how make this code work

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user should not be able to enter `\n` in the password box. But anyway, to avoid infinite calling, you could try something like this:

```
private void PasswordBox_A_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PasswordBox_A.Password.Contains("\n"))
        PasswordBox_A.Password = PasswordBox_A.Password.Replace("\n", "");
}
```

Comment: great it works! you said that the user shouldn't be able to enter /n. is there a way to make this possible? is the same thing i'm trying to do..

Comment: I just added a `PasswordBox` to a WPF form, and I cannot enter `\n` The control does seem to have anything like `TextBox.AcceptsReturn`. How did you enter a new line?